# Improve apache hive performance

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have 5GB of data in my HDFS sink. When I run any query on Hive it takes more than 10-15 minutes to complete. The number of rows I get when I run,

```
select count(*) from table_name
```

is 3,880,900. My VM has 4.5 GB mem and it runs on MBP 2012. I would like to know if creating index in the table will have any performance improvement. Also are there any other ways to tell hive to only use this much amount of data or rows so as to get results faster? I am ok even if the queries are run for a lesser subset of data at least to get a glimpse of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indexing should help. However, getting a subset of data (using limit) isn't really helpful as hive still scans the whole data before limiting the output.

You can try using RCFile/ORCFile format for faster results. In my experiments, RCFile based tables executed queries roughly 10 times faster than textfile/sequence file based tables.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you are querying you can get gains by using the different file formats like ORC, Parquet.   What kind of data are you querying, is it structured or unstructured data?  What kind of queries are you trying to perform?  If it is structured data you can see gains also by using other SQL on Hadoop solutions such as InfiniDB, Presto, Impala etc...

I am an architect for InfiniDB
http://infinidb.co
SQL on Hadoop solutions like InfiniDB, Impala and others work by you loading your data through them at which they will perform calculations, optimizations etc... to make that data faster to query.  This helps tremendously for interactive analytical queries, especially when compared to something like Hive.

With that said, you are working with 5GB of data (but data always grows! someday could be TBs), which is pretty small so you can still work in the worlds of the some of the tools that are not intended for high performance queries.   Your best solution with Hive is to look at how your data is and see if ORC or Parquet could benefit your queries (columnar formats are good for analytic queries).

Hive is always going to be one of the slower options though for performing SQL queries on your HDFS data.  Hortonworks with their Stinger initiative is making it better, you might want to check that out.
http://hortonworks.com/labs/stinger/

Answer (score 0):

The use case sounds fit for ORC, Parquet if you are interested in a subset of the columns. ORC with hive 0.12 comes with PPD which will help you discarding blocks while running the queries using the meta data that it stores for each column.

We did an implementation on top of hive to support bloom filters in the meta data indexes for ORC files which gave a performance gain of 5-6X.

What is average number of Mapper/Reducer tasks launched for the queries you execute? Tuning some parameters can definitely help.